# AS3 Setting Visible Property of MovieClips

Tags: actionscript-3

Can I set the "visible" property of a movie clip every frame or should I check the current state of the "visible" property to decide if it needs to be updated?

Is setting the "visible" property to the same value cheap or not? Please provide a source.

Comment: I believe there is underlying code that will just ignore the change if it's the same as what's already set, so knock yourself out.

Comment: some source would be nice - I am concerned that there may be some "dirty flag" that is set when setting the visible property

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that in pure Flash. I don't believe that is the mental model the Flash Engineers used (Flex, absolutely, worry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

The `visible` property is simply a flag that is set and then read the next time the DisplayList renders. Updating its value doesn't actually do anything other than set an internal property used for drawing the object to the value you supply. You can modify the value of `visible` multiple times each frame and it would perform the same.

Basically, when Flash runs over all of the DisplayObjects that you have added to the DisplayList, it checks a collection of flags and values that each has, like `x`, `y`, `alpha` and `visible`. It uses these values to determine what to do about drawing the object. When you make an object not visible, all that really happens is Flash will skip that object and not attempt to draw it.

For tidiness, I would just stick with not having the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is underlying code to prevent it being set to the same value, as Amy mentioned, but if you want to be absolutely sure, you could do this instead:

```
if ( !mc.visible ) {
    mc.visible = true;
}
```

and do the opposite if you are setting it as false.

```
if ( mc.visible ) {
    mc.visible = false;
}
```

That will only change the value if it is not already set to that value. You obviously want to make sure those are never next to each other, because your component would *always* end up with visible = false.

Comment: I am currently using "if (mc.visible != myValue) mc.visible = myValue;"

Comment: @AmyBlankenship It does, but it would prevent the setting from being set (I was unaware of how the visible setting was actually set before Marty Wallace posted his answer), which is what the Schifty had asked about.